# Create a link that can show an route/itinerary in different applications

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps, mobile-website

I'd like to create a link in my website that can redirect to a route/itinerary (I don't know the exact word, I don't speak English very well) in other applications.

Let me explain. I know I can just create a link to Google Maps, with, for example, this https://www.google.com/maps/dir/48,2/51.49637,-0.13877/

But what I'd like to do is letting the mobile's user choose the application he wants to use. With an android phone, he would have to choose what application he uses.

I know it's possible when developping an application, but does anyone know if it's possible to do this in a website ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything you can do from the web side to control this, the device sees the link and chooses it from there based on what applications can run it on the phone. For example youtube links in chrome give you the option to handle it in the app or the browser.

Comment: Yes but isn't there a special protocole ? a "universal" url ? Or a way to trigger a "route" event with Javascript ?